# When does IIS _gracefully_ stop/restart applications?

Tags: iis, web-applications

As far as I understand, IIS-hosted applications can stop or restart for a variety of reasons, including:

- A person explicitly telling it to using the stop button in IIS manager.
- [Automatically restarting an application for one of various reasons](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/08/02/asp-net-case-study-lost-session-variables-and-appdomain-recycles.aspx). (In particular, when a the application's physical path is changed in IIS.)

**When this happens, does it do so gracefully or forcefully?**

By *gracefully*, I mean without stopping the application in the middle of processing a request; it should finish what it's doing and then follow its normal shut down procedures for the application.

Answer (score 0):

IIS will attempt to allow workers to finish, but *will* forcefully terminate them if they take too long to stop (usually a few seconds). To get around this, you can use `iisreset /noforce` to make IIS wait until everything is done.

Comment: Thanks; that option looks useful. However, I was wondering more about restarting/stopping individual *applications* rather than IIS as a whole. Also, what do you think about the second dot-point?